# OpenERP - Can I just get city name in my form field with "res.better.zip"?

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

I have a custom form that inherit city from "res.better.zip", this is the python code:

```
city= fields.Many2one('res.better.zip', 'City:')
```

but when I search for a city, it autofill with "zip code, city, state and country", can I only get the "city" in this field?

P.D. this is the field in the .xml

```
<field name="city" class="oe_no_button" placeholder="p. ej. Madrid" options="{&quot;no_open&quot;: True}" attrs="{'readonly': [('city','=',True)]}"/>
```

Comment: Mariusz' answer seems correct, but could you please improve your question (maybe for later use) and give us the class definition of `res.better.zip`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly, what you need to do is define _rec_name on your res.better.zip model, like:

```
_rec_name = 'city'
```

Note that will change default name for whole model res.better.zip.